# linux file permission got a ending . dot and webserver denied access

Tags: linux, centos6, file-permissions

I have got a issue that I never have seen before.
A lot of my files and folders have changed file permission to a persiion ending whit a dot filesystem is

```
/dev/md3        /var    ext4    defaults

-rw-rw-rw-. 1 apache apache 14K Sep 28  2015 /media/thumbs/embedded/1664949.jpg
```

Does any one know how to fix this??

Comment: I suppose there is an issue with SELinux (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) and maybe this article can help you: http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/

Comment: getenforce Disabled and cat /etc/selinux/ = SELINUX=permissive

Answer (score 3):

> GNU 'ls' uses a '.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
>        security context, but no other alternate access method.

Your system has SELinux installed and enabled, there really isn't anything you need to do.

> getenforce Disabled and cat /etc/selinux/ = SELINUX=permissive

SELinux really isn't causing your problem you will need to look elsewhere.

> SeLinux is disabled and even if I re-chcon it's the same

SELinux really isn't causing your problem you will need to look elsewhere.

Comment: SeLinux is disabled and even if I re-chcon it's the same

Comment: That is also what I thought...

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work

But it didn't solve my issue about why lighttpd can't access same files and apache can't

But that might be another thread

Comment: The question you asked, and the answer you link to are entirely unrelated. It's time for you to step away from the computer and find another career, you're not suited to this one.

Comment: They are completely related time for you to find your glassess

Comment: I believe both are wrong:

- @Iain this answer is not from the same user from the question

- user355906 I believe you answer the wrong question. I believe you wanted http://serverfault.com/questions/778438/lighttpd-cant-access-same-files-and-apache-cant

So, I guess it's time for both of you wake up from the keyboard, relax and comback with your glassess :)

Comment: The question was about the dot after file permission -rw-rw-rw-. and that was answered in the link i posted answer #1  Other users started to talk about SeLinux which had nothing to do with the question